# app inventor webviewer can't upload files from a html form

Tags: app-inventor

I have made a html/php form that allows me to upload files. And when I open it in my pc browser works perfectly. It also works when I open this website wiht my mobile's browser and when I click on select file I can chose which app I want to use to get the file I want to upload.

But when I open this website with `webviewer` from my app, When I click the button to upload the sound,  nothing happens. The whole line is selected and clicking the button does nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webviewer` is no full browser, this does not work therefore.
But you can use the `activity starter` instead, see the documentation about [Using the Activity Starter](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/using-activity-starter.html)

> **Open the browser to a Web page** 
>   Use these activity starter properties
>   to open a specific web page:
>
> **Action**: android.intent.action.VIEW 
>   **DataUri**: http://news.google.com

Alternatively use the `web` component together with the `PostFile` block, see an example [here](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php)

Comment: I already know how to use the browser with **activity starter** but I was looking for a way to put the form insed the app.

It seams that I will have to redo my form inside my app. I am going to read your tutorial right now.

Thanks again Taifun.